# Writing iOS app for customer, customer submitting it?

Tags: ios, deployment, submission

I'm currently in the situation of writing an iOS application for a client.

The client wants to submit the app (.ipa package) to the app store himself, with his developer profile. Mainly because he want to have his name in the App Store rather than mine.

Could this procedure cause issues? For example signing issues?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The application has to be signed with the certificates for the account under which it will be submitted. Your options include handing over the entire project and source code when the project is complete, or, develop the project as a developer of their account with their development and distribution certificates.

Answer (score 1):

There is another option : you could ask the login and password of your client. So you'll create a distribution profile for your Mac, and all the other components for your application. When app is delivered on Itune Connect, your client may change its password.

That way, you can handle everything for him, and that could be usefull if he's not very able with techno stuff, but still want to have an app with his name.